# finding array rows that satisfy conditions on two column values

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy integer array with many rows and 3 columns.  A sample is shown.  The 2nd and 3rd columns represent indices, and each 2nd column value is < the corresponding 3rd column value.

I also have a variable k.  For this example, I'll use **k = 4**.

TASK: **I want to find all array rows where k is strictly NOT BETWEEN the values in the 2nd and 3rd columns**.  So, in each 'surviving' row, the 2nd and 3rd column values will both be < k, or both be > k.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[-1, 0, 6],
                [-6, 1, 2],
                [-8, 3, 10],
                [ 3, 4, 11],
                [-2, 5, 9],
                [-4, 7, 8]])  

m = arr[((arr[:,1] > k) & (arr[:,2] > k)) | ((arr[:,1] < k) & (arr[:,2] < k))]
```

The code for m (above) works fine, correctly producing the following array:

```
[[-6, 1, 2],
 [-2, 5, 9],
 [-4, 7, 8]]
```

Here's my question - is it possible to simplify or better formulate m? 
  I've tried slicing (ie: using arr[:,1:]  or  arr[:,[1,2]] in the expression for m) without success.  Also, I'm a bit sketchy on whether the '|' is the proper way to execute a logical 'or'.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use vector algebraic operations. I am not sure if it simplifies but it is funky though.

```py
arr[np.prod(arr[...,1:3] < k, axis=1) + np.prod(arr[...,1:3] > k, axis=1) > 0,:]
```

The logic behind is to check both columns if they are lower (or bigger) than `k` and multiply the results which corresponds to an `and` and then add up the resulting vectors and check if they are bigger than 1 which should correspond to the  `or`.

Comment: Very educational!  Thanks.
%timeit rates both methods as being very close.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [numpy.compress](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.compress.html#numpy.compress) "Return selected slices of an array along given axis" to replace the `m = arr[]`

```
import numpy as np

k = 4
arr = np.array([[-1, 0, 6],
                [-6, 1, 2],
                [-8, 3, 10],
                [3, 4, 11],
                [-2, 5, 9],
                [-4, 7, 8]])

cond_val = (((arr[:, 1] > k)
            & (arr[:, 2] > k))
            | ((arr[:, 1] < k)
            & (arr[:, 2] < k)))

m = np.compress(cond_val, arr, axis=0)
```

Note: The condition is the same, just put in a variable and separated by lines.

Comment: Very nice.   There's a few other places I can put np.compress to work.